# How to execute multiple global commands in Vim not sequentially?

Tags: global-command

Using following test input:

```
***********
aaa
bbb
ccc
***********
ddd
eee
fff
-----------
ggg
hhh
iii
-----------
jjj
kkk
lll
-----------
***********
aaa
bbb
ccc
***********
ddd
eee
fff
-----------
```

Following method is close to what i'm looking for:

(i'm in need of using different ranges for each matches)

```
:execute 'g/ccc/-0,+0#' | execute 'g/eee/-1,+2#'

  4 ccc     <<----------- first returns lines with ccc, then with eee
 21 ccc
  6 ddd
  7 eee
  8 fff
  9 -----------
 23 ddd
 24 eee
 25 fff
 26 -----------
```

Above output seems to show that the multiple global commands are executed sequentially.  So, i get the "ccc" matches first from first global.  Then comes the next set of matches from second global.

Is there way to run these global matches/commands on each lines in a single pass?

How would i go about getting following output instead?

```
  4 ccc
  6 ddd
  7 eee
  8 fff
  9 -----------
 21 ccc     <<-----------
 23 ddd
 24 eee
 25 fff
 26 -----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the way the `:g` command works. If you execute two `:g` commands *after each other*, do not be surprised, if they will be executed *after each other* :)

So you need to do it in one single pass. For that match the lines with a single `:g` command and then execute the `#` depending on the line content with different ranges. Something like this should work:

```
:g/eee\|ccc/if getline('.')=~'eee'|.-,.+2#|else|#|endif
```

Note: No `:exe` needed in this case.

Comment: Though if i was writing it in this case i would go with `… execute (getline('.') =~# 'eee' ? '-,+2' : '') '#'`